# Como declarar una variable condicionado a si existe o no python

Tags: python, funciones, condiciones, python-3.7, programación-funcional

Tengo un modulo que transforma e importa un conjunto de DataFrames y los concatena llamado `UPataPrep` que funciona perfectamente

Tengo un modulo llamado `M_Pred` que predice de la siguiente forma múltiples modelos:

```
class Pred() :

def __init__(self):
    self.dff = UPDataPrep().get_transformed_data()


def a(self):

    print("***Forecasting***")

    model = keras.models.load_model("model_local_a.h5")

    # Prediccion
    Yp=model.predict(self.dff)
    Yp_df=pd.DataFrame(data=Yp[:,1], columns=['a'])
    Yp_df=pd.concat([ids,Yp_df],axis=1)
    
    return Yp_df


def b (self):

    print("***Forecasting***")

    model = keras.models.load_model("model_local_b.h5")

    # Prediccion
    Yp=model.predict(self.dff)
    Yp_df=pd.DataFrame(data=Yp[:,1], columns=['b'])
    Yp_df=pd.concat([ids,Yp_df],axis=1)
    
    return Yp_df
```

Cuando creo una funcion main desde la que ejecutaré todo el código de esta manera

```
from M_Pred import Pred

def run_preduction():
    Pred().a()
    Pred().b()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_preduction ()
```

¿Existe alguna manera de que un condicional verifique si ya existe `dff` antes de volver a declararla desde `UPDataPrep().get_transformed_data()` para evitar que importe los datos una y otra vez desde la funcion `main`? (este proceso resulta ser muy lento porque son muchos modelos e importa los mismos datos una y otra vez)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta respuesta uso muy seguido la palabra "instancia", aquí te dejo una cita de una pagina web con un agregado mio de que es una instancia:

```
-Las clases agrupan objetos con propiedades y características en común, por ejemplo (Perros)
-Instancia significa crear un objeto a partir de una clase. Por ejemplo, una instancia de Perro podría ser Firulais.
```

Mas info en [https://pythones.net/variables-de-clases/#:~:text=Instancia%20significa%20crear%20un%20objeto,clase%20utilizando%20variables%20de%20instancia](https://pythones.net/variables-de-clases/#:%7E:text=Instancia%20significa%20crear%20un%20objeto,clase%20utilizando%20variables%20de%20instancia).

---

Si hay una forma. Primero que podrías crear `dff` como un atributo que sea compartido por todas las instancias de `Pred`. Entonces el atributo no se "setea" cada vez que llamas a tu class.

Luego puedes usar la función incorporada `hasattr` para saber si Pred tiene el atributo `dff` y si lo tiene que no vuelva a importar los datos.
Entonces, el código de tu función quedaría así:

```
def run_preduction():
    if(not hasattr(Pred, "dff")):
        Pred.dff = UPDataPrep().get_transformed_data()

    Pred().a()
    Pred().b()
```

Y así tendría que quedar tu `__init__` de Pred:

```
def __init__(self):
    #Quitamos esta linea por que ya importas los datos de otro modo
    #self.dff = UPDataPrep().get_transformed_data()

    """ El resto del código de tu init """
```

De esta manera, los datos solo se importan cuando llamas a la función `run_preduction` por primera vez.
Si esta función está destinada a llamarse una sola vez, entonces no es necesario que uses hasattr.

También podrías hacer que los datos se importen apenas importas tu modulo así:

```
class Pred() :
    if __name__ == '__main__'
        dff = UPDataPrep().get_transformed_data()

    def __init__(self):
        """ Tu código """
```

Al declararse dentro del class decir `dff = (valor)` es como decir `Pred.dff = (valor)` fuera del class.

También es posible que lo que realmente busques es usar la misma instancia de la clase para el metodo `a()` y `b()`. En ese caso, deja el código de tu modulo intacto y pon el siguiente código en tu programa principal:

```
from M_Pred import Pred

def run_preduction():
    #Esto hace que se llame la función `__init__` y te devuelve una instancia de Pred().
    pred = Pred()

    #llamo al metodo a. __init__ NO se ejecuta por que no creo una nueva instancia.
    pred.a()

    #Pasa lo mismo aqui.
    pred.b()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_preduction ()
```

Recuerda, la diferencia entre `Pred().a()` y `pred.a()` es que en el primer caso creas una nueva instancia, en el segundo recurres a una ya existente.
`__init__` se llama cada vez que creas una nueva instancia. Y eso sucede cuando pones `()` al lado de la clase.

Avisame si no te funciona, ya que no pude probar el código. Y perdona si no pude explicarme bien, ojala me hayas entendido, no soy bueno escribiendo respuestas jajaja